# Download files from google drive via URL

Tags: google-drive-api

We are planning on opening a company account on google drive which will be accessible to only company people.

The issue is we want to put several files on our drive and download them programatically. We tried using google drive APIs but the download speed it very low.

Then we also tried wget but that requires that all the files are made public which we cannot do.

Is there any way to use wget with credentials which will allow a file to be downloaded via an URL.

Our typical file size is 50GB.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a command from wget to specify user and password. Have you tried the following?

```
wget --user='username' --ask-'password' https://docs.google.com/'ItemType'/Export='DocumentId'
```